# Upgrade vc++6 project to vc++ 2008 from command line

Tags: command-line, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2008

I'm trying to upgrade vc++6 project (.dsp) to vc++2008 project (.vcproj)
i'm using vc++ 2008 express edition

the file upgraded and built successfully from IDE
but i need to do it from the command line to script building it among other projects

So, I tried this:

1* "devenv.exe" >> Not available with the express edition

2* "vcexpress.exe" >> Supports commandline options but not /upgrade

3* "vcbuild.exe" and "msbuild.exe"  >> Supports /upgrade option but giving fatal error
                                       ("unable to convert")

4* using com object "VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.9.0" and the its method "LoadProject"
   but it returns unhandled exception.

After some searching, found a result that says that the file styled with linux line feeds"
and this is the cause for the problem so, I converted the file to windows style using Notepad++ and repeated the steps but no luck.

So, Is there any method to convert the project from command line?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, and after extensive search, there is no way to upgrade this 
kind of projects.

If anyone is searching for answer, You have to write makefile for this project 
to build it from the command line with :

```
nmake /f "makefile"
```